# Tooltip on Listview Item click listner don't work

Tags: android, tooltip

Tooltip on Listview Item click listner don't work

This Library add my project
compile 'com.github.douglasjunior:android-simple-tooltip:0.2.0'

```
final  SimpleTooltip tooltip = new SimpleTooltip.Builder(v.getContext())
                                .anchorView(v)
                                .text("Results")
                                .dismissOnOutsideTouch(true)
                                .dismissOnInsideTouch(false)
                            .contentView(R.layout.tooltip,R.id.tv_result_header)
                              .textColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green))
                                .gravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                                .build();
                        tooltip.show();
ArrayList<Result_ModelList> Result_list = new ArrayList<Result_ModelList>();
                        Listview lv=(Listview)tooltip.findViewById(R.id.lv);
                      Result_list.add(new Result_ModelList("Alphabetically"));
                      Result_list.add(new Result_ModelList("By Code"));
                      Result_list.add(new Result_ModelList("Last created"));

Result_Adapter adapter = new Sort_Result_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.raw_result,Result_list);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

//**Do not work**
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "do not work" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
 });
```

Comment: what's the v in `anchorView(v)`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the [Usage](https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip) section?

```
Listview lv=(Listview)tooltip.findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
long id) {
    new SimpleTooltip.Builder(this)
    .anchorView(view)
    .text("Something")
    .gravity(Gravity.END)
    .animated(true)
    .transparentOverlay(false)
    .build()
    .show();
 }
 });
```

If you want to show it on a particular item on ListView you can use 
`View v=lv.getChildAt(position);`
and use it as anchor view
        `anchorView(v)`

to show it on first item do this:

```
ArrayList<Result_ModelList> Result_list = new ArrayList<Result_ModelList>();
                    Listview lv=(Listview)tooltip.findViewById(R.id.lv);
                  Result_list.add(new 
Result_ModelList("Alphabetically"));
                  Result_list.add(new Result_ModelList("By Code"));
                  Result_list.add(new Result_ModelList("Last created"));

Result_Adapter adapter = new Sort_Result_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.raw_result,Result_list);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "do not work" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
 });

View view=lv.getChildAt(0);
 SimpleTooltip tooltip = new SimpleTooltip.Builder(v.getContext())
                            .anchorView(view) //if you want to display on whole listview do .anchorView(lv)
                            .text("Results")
                            .dismissOnOutsideTouch(true)
                            .dismissOnInsideTouch(false)
                        .contentView(R.layout.tooltip,R.id.tv_result_header)
                          .textColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green))
                            .gravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                            .build();
                    tooltip.show();
```

Comment: tooltip having listview and i want to item click listner of listvew not work

Comment: if you want to show on some items of listview only, then after you have called `setAdapter()` use this code with `lv.getChildAt(position_you_want)` as `anchorView`.

Comment: can you describe properly ?

Comment: I'm not getting what you want to do. do you want to show tooltip on some items or on all of them?